# Unity: Problem with Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm drawing using LineRenderer but I enable and disable the gameobject where the script is at different times.

The first enable it works perfect, after I disable and enable, I get this error

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

error shows to this line of code

```
Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.touches[0].position);
```

Here is all the code

```
public GameObject linePrefab;
private Line activeLine;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            GameObject lineGO = Instantiate(linePrefab);
            activeLine = lineGO.GetComponent<Line>();
        }

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            activeLine = null;
        }
    }

    if (activeLine != null)
    {
        Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.touches[0].position);
        activeLine.UpdateLine(touchPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming the user is touching the screen in your code.

You need to check if there are any active touches before processing the touch position.  Specifically, you can add to your if check whether or not Input.touchCount > 0

Comment: Sorry, just to add:  I see you do that check earlier, but note the line in question is not in that block.